# Discrete wavelet transform for image texture analysis

Tags: image-processing, classification, feature-extraction, wavelet, haar-wavelet

I am planning to use the discrete wavelet transform to extract textural features from grayscale images for classification purpose. However, I am not sure which type of wavelet should I choose? most of the studies I read, using  Haar or Daubechies wavelets when extracting features from images.
So, is there a way to determine which wavelet is suitable?

Answer (score 0):

You may test your images and observe wavelet coefficients in any resolution (level of decomposition, time/scale) that a wavelet transformation will return to you, based on which you may design a simple equation as an objective function to select the base function (e.g., `Haar`, `Daubechies 4`, `Daubechies 12`, `Morlet`, `Coiflet`) for you by a simple `for` loop.